# how to test C# fax program?

Tags: c#, testing, fax

How do i test my own C# program in order to send a fax?

```
namespace FAX
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendFax(textBox1.Text,openFileDialog1.FileName,textBox2.Text,textBox3.Text);


        }

        public void SendFax(string DocumentName, string FileName, string RecipientName, string FaxNumber)
        {
            if (FaxNumber != "")
            {
                int response = 0;
                FAXCOMLib.FaxServer faxServer = new FAXCOMLib.FaxServerClass();
                try
                {
                    faxServer.Connect("");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
                FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc faxDoc = (FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc)faxServer.CreateDocument(FileName);
                try
                {
                    faxDoc.FaxNumber = FaxNumber;
                    faxDoc.RecipientName = RecipientName;
                    faxDoc.DisplayName = DocumentName;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
                try
                {
                    response = faxDoc.Send();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
                try
                {
                    faxServer.Disconnect();
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
                }

            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            openFileDialog1.Filter = " doc file|*.doc";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
           string Filepath = "";
            Filepath = openFileDialog1.FileName;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not test it with the real device? if you're not getting any errors that is

Answer (score 4):

Attach the fax (real device) and swithc on it.

1. Run your program and send fax. (ensure you're able to get information about fax delivery)
2. The same scenario like (1) but in the middle of transmition detach the cabble (check how your program is fault tollerant)
3. The same scenario like (1) but with fax switched OFF. (check on connection timeout and all that stuff)

After this tests you're already at good point.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of something like Unit Testing, I would suggest to  declare an interface IFax (with a method called SendFax probably) and put SendFax into a module that implements this module. Your Fax-class can be tested without class 'Form1' then with the real device (If you want to test at another level, you might encapsulate the FAXCOMLIB behind an interface and the same applies then). To test the GUI behavior, you can implement IFax by a class 'ErrorThrowingTestFax' class that always throws an error or a DoNothingTestFax that never does anything or whatever you want.